# Convert complex JSON to one-level POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's imagine you have the following JSON:

```
{
  "prop0": "value0",
  "level1" : {
      "prop1": "value1"
      "prop2": "value2"
   },
   ....
}
```

Can it be turned to simple Java object?

```
class Pojo {
  private String prop0;
  private String prop1;
  private String prop2;
}
```

I don't want to create a intermediate class to wrap "level1".

What is come to my mind is to map my class in this way:

```
class Pojo {
  private String prop0;
  @JsonProperty("level1.prop1")
  private String prop1;
  @JsonProperty("level1.prop2")
  private String prop2;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. The inverse problem - turn complex Java object to plain JSON can be simply solved using `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation.

Can you please suggest any workable solution for my issue?

Comment: You could use a custom de-serializer.

Comment: What else is there at the root of your JSON?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Of course the JSON object is more complex. I just simplified the structure as it's not essential for the question.

Comment: For the solution I want to propose it is. I don't need to know specifics, just whether or not there are other key value pairs at the root.

Comment: @Mena Of I can use custom de-serializer but it complicates the understanding of the code. Annotations are much more preferrable.

Comment: @DzmitryZahusta I totally agree. Only, I'm not aware of any solution through annotations - but maybe someone else is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either write a custom deserializer, or add a setter that can transform the structure. For latter you could do something like

```
...
public void setLevel1(Map<String,String> values) { // or JsonNode
   prop1 = values.get("prop1");
   // and so forth; if names are regular, can use looping
}
```